# Can you see any vulnerabilities in the following SQL Injection defense scheme?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, security, sql-injection

1. Instead of storing apostrophes (`'`) in character fields in your database, always translate apostrophes to some unique substitute symbol that isn't recognized as SQL syntax and isn't likely to be commonly-found or meaningful in your data.
2. When receiving direct user input such as from GET, POST, etc., always filter out any apostrophes in the values by translating them to your chosen substitute symbol.
3. For all SQL statements that incorporate user input, always wrap apostrophes around literal values.  For example, like this: `SELECT Name FROM Client WHERE TYPE = '1';`.  This should force all non-apostrophe characters to be treated as part of the literal value itself, regardless if they are back-quotes, curly braces, semi-colons, back-slashes, forward-slashes, etc.  So something like `SELECT Name FROM Client WHERE TYPE = ' -- /* comment the rest ';` wouldn't be interpreted differently.
4. Whenever incorporating user input into a non-literal portion of a SQL statement (such as a column name in an ORDER BY clause), filter out punctuation from the value altogether, or validate it against a pre-defined safe set.
5. Whenever outputting data (to HTML, XML, etc.) from your database, always reverse this filtering process by replacing your chosen substitute symbols with apostrophes so things are nicely readable for clients.

(Note: We're using SQL Server, which doesn't recognize back-quote symbols as valid SQL punctuation, but if using MySQL, we would also need to translate back-quotes.)

I've tested this with every imaginable symbol that could choke SQL and so far it has withstood everything.  Have I overlooked anything?  I wanted to get some community feedback before I tried this on a production system.

---

Our environment:

- Linux (not Windows)
- PHP 5.4
- ADOdb version ? (documentation: older = http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm ; newer = http://adodb.sourceforge.net/)
- Driver = "mssql"

Comment: i don't like the idea of changing the data because then you open yourself up to the possibility of data loss. any reason prepared statements aren't enough?

Comment: We're unfortunately using a legacy ADODB driver with PHP. It doesn't support parameterized SQL like the newer PDO driver does.

Comment: @JohnDoe That detail needs to be added to the question. But what version of PHP are you using? I assume this is running on Windows? Are you referring to this ADODB usage: http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php ? Or perhaps this: http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm ? What version of the ADODB driver?

Comment: No worries - all reactions welcome.  Linux.  PHP 5.4.  The second link for ADODB.  It apparently hasn't been updated since 2012, not supported (or used much) any more.  We have tens of thousands of lines of legacy code based on it, which is why we haven't refactored for PDO.

Comment: @JohnDoe It has been updated since that link. I also found its new home: http://adodb.sourceforge.net/ and the code now lives at https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb . It looks like it still has some minimal development activity. What version of the ADOdb library are you using? And which connection type? "mssql" or "mssqlpo" or "odbc_mssql"?

Comment: We are using "mssql".  I believe we're on the latest version, or whatever the latest version was a year ago.

Comment: Well, that should be good news then because looking at even the outdated doc (copyright up to 2012 -- v5.18), ADOdb _does_ support both parameterized queries _and_ Stored Procedures (which are inherently parameterized): please see http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#prepare and http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#preparesp . They even mention PDO ( go here and its the next subsection:  http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#connect_ex ) but I'm not sure if that is helpful or useless ( also see http://adodb.sourceforge.net/docs-adodb.htm#php5 ).

Comment: Sweet jeez, I'll be damned. Thanks.  The homebrew hack was pure badassity, but this will work even better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the MySQL side of things, but since this is mainly about SQL Server, I can say that this approach gains you nothing that parameterizing your queries and/or using Stored Procedures doesn't already get you. However, it does have the following drawbacks:

1. It takes time to implement
2. It make the system more error prone (i.e. places that forget to do the translation)
3. It makes the data less portable / exportable / reportable since all clients will need to know of this non-obvious translation
4. With regards to doing `SELECT Name FROM Cient WHERE TYPE = '1';`, if the `TYPE` field is a numeric type then you will at best be hurting performance, and at worst getting conversion errors
5. You now have an unnecessarily over-complicated system that will increase training and support times (getting new programmers up to speed, time it takes to find / fix problems, etc).

Just use parameters, whether as inputs to Stored Procedures, or parameterized ad hoc SQL statements. If using .NET, it would be using `SqlParameter`s in both cases.

**ADOdb** does support both parameterized queries and Stored Procedures (which are inherently parameterized). Please see:

- http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#prepare, and
- http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#preparesp

They even mention PDO ( go here and its the next subsection: http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#connect_ex ) but I'm not sure if that is helpful or useless. PDO is also mentioned here: http://adodb.sourceforge.net/docs-adodb.htm#php5.

Comment: It would be nice to use parameterized SQL.  :)  But in this case, we're using a legacy ADODB driver with PHP.  It doesn't support parameterized SQL like the newer PDO driver does.

Comment: @JohnDoe I updated with the ADOdb links showing that you should be able to do both parameterized queries and Stored Procedures :-).